# FormData File Upload with Progress Listener Content-Type header missing

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, file-upload

I am building a client-server application with a java-server (no JSP, just `com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer;`) and web frontend as client. I use WebSockets for communication and want to upload files with XMLHttpRequests and FormData (i followed this post [Track ajax post progress for fileupload using jquery ajax and FormData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14002393/track-ajax-post-progress-for-fileupload-using-jquery-ajax-and-formdata)). I want to track the upload progress with `xhr.upload.onprogress`, but as soon as i add a listener such as

```
xhr.upload.onprogress = function(e) {...};
```

or

```
xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function (e) {...}, false);
```

i get an serverside error like this:

```
org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$InvalidContentTypeException: the request doesn't contain a multipart/form-data or multipart/mixed stream, content type header is null
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileItemIteratorImpl.<init>(FileUploadBase.java:948)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.getItemIterator(FileUploadBase.java:310)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:334)
    at com.awaker.server.HttpUploadServer.handle(HttpUploadServer.java:42)
    at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:79)
    at sun.net.httpserver.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:83)
    at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:82)
    at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange$LinkHandler.handle(ServerImpl.java:675)
    at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:79)
    at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange.run(ServerImpl.java:647)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I use the [Apache Commons FileUpload](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/index.html) framework for handling upload requests.

This occurs in Firefox and Opera (the only browsers i tested), and while the correct Content-Type headers are listed in Firebug/developer console, the server does not receives this header (same goes for Content-Length header).

It doesn't matter if i use jQuery ajax

```
$.ajax({
           url: "http://host...",
           type: "POST",
           data: ajaxData,
           cache: false,
           contentType: false,
           processData: false,
           xhr: function () {
               var xhr = jQuery.ajaxSettings.xhr();
               if (xhr.upload) {
                   xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function (e) {
                    console.log("hello");
                    }, false);
               }
               return xhr;
           }
       });
```

or vanilla js

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.upload.onprogress = uploader.uploadProgress;
xhr.open("POST", "http://host...");
xhr.send(formData);
```

i always get the same error.
As soon as i remove the onprogress-handler, everything works fine.
I already tried this [FormData boundary missing from content-type in POST request header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27744470/formdata-boundary-missing-from-content-type-in-post-request-header), but this doesn't work for me, too.

Does anybody know how to solve this?
Thank you!

Edit: 
The ajaxData are generated from an drop event:

```
    var droppedFiles = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;
    var ajaxData = new FormData();
    ajaxData.append("file", droppedFiles[0]);
```

The contentType: false option lets jQuery/XHR automatically add the Content-Type header with the neccessary boundary. This option is required, it doesn't work without it.

Edit2: 
This works fine

```
$.ajax({
           url: "http://host...",
           type: "POST",
           data: ajaxData,
           cache: false,
           contentType: false,
           processData: false,
           xhr: function () {
               var xhr = jQuery.ajaxSettings.xhr();
               return xhr;
           }
       });
```

It seems that only adding the progress listener makes a difference.

Edit3:
Here is the serverside code that throws the error:

```
@Override
public void handle(HttpExchange httpExchange) throws IOException {
    DiskFileItemFactory diskFileItemFactory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
    ServletFileUpload fileUpload = new ServletFileUpload(diskFileItemFactory);

    try {
        List<FileItem> result = fileUpload.parseRequest(new HttpHandlerRequestContext(httpExchange));
        (...)
    } catch (FileUploadException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

i followed this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/33827895/6655315.
The HttpHandlerRequestContext is exactly the same as shown in the linked post.

Edit4:
just by adding an empty upload progress handler like this

```
 xhr.upload.onprogress = function(e) {};
```

the received headers are changing from this

```
Accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
Origin: http://localhost:63343
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost...
Connection: keep-alive
Host: localhost:4734
Dnt: 1
User-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0
Accept-language: de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------63422017421660
Content-length: 333700
```

to this:

```
Accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
Access-control-request-method: POST
Origin: http://localhost:63343
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Connection: keep-alive
Host: localhost:4734
Dnt: 1
User-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0
Accept-language: de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
```

Comment: remove `contentType: false,` jq should handle the rest

Comment: Thanks, but that doesnt work since I'm using FormData, for which the Content-Type header needs the boundary. Removing this leads to the error above.

Comment: Did you ever figure out why the onprogress event handler was changing the header and what the fix for that is?

Comment: @shreddish i found no solution, so i switched to uploading the files one after another

Comment: So I have found the solution to my problem which may not be exactly your situation. I was posting to a CORS url (a different domain) and found that registering for an "on progress" event forces the browser to perform a "preflight CORS check". A "preflight CORS check" sends an http OPTION request before performing the file upload. This OPTION request is to ask the server for its CORS functionality. My server code was not responding to that request so the browser was stripping all of the correct headers for the actual file upload.

Comment: my error occured when experimenting in my local network, so this could be the error source. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have your answer in the exception.

In both examples you didn't set the Content-Type header so it is indeed missing.

[Adding request headers to XHR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/setRequestHeader)

[jQuery ajax API](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

I would also recommend reading about [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I'm already using FormData (see edit). The Content-Type header with boundary inclusive should be added automatically, but this is only missing when using `xhr.upload.onprogress`

Comment: its specified here https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-XMLHttpRequest-20120117/#the-send-method at section "if data is a FormData".

Comment: It says that the mime-type should be set. That doesn't mean that the Content-Type header will be set.

Comment: Can you try setting the progress listener directly to the XHR instance? like `xhr.onprogress = function (e) {}`? also instantiate the xhr instance using the vanilla constructor instead of `jQuery.ajaxSettings.xhr()`

Comment: Thanks again. Using `new XMLHttpRequest()` has the same result. `xhr.onprogress` works, but this is only for the download progress. i want to track the upload progress with `xhr.upload.onprogress` like specified here https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-XMLHttpRequest-20120117/#the-upload-attribute

Comment: I went over your question again and noticed you said you saw the header on the request. That means I just wasted time trying to fix the client side.. Sorry about that.

Comment: Is there anything else parsing the reauest before it gets to the FileUpload class?

Comment: Thank you very much! Nothing else is parsing the request (except HttpExchange i guess). I just added the server side code and the full headers before and after adding a handler and noticed that the accept header has changed, too. But Im still clueless...